# Passing props (array) into a router-link path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-props

I'm trying to dynamically update a `<router-link>` path based on what view component it is used within. Below is the `<router-link>` that is looping through the `compItems` array which is populated by each view component.

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: compItem.name, params: { compItems: compItem.router } }" class="cz-ds-view-related-comp" v-for="compItem in compItems" :key="compItem.name">
  <div class="related-comp_icon"><img class="related-comp_icon" :src="require('@/assets/home/icons/' + compItem.atomicIcon + '')" alt=""></div>
  <div class="related-comp_title"><h3>{{ compItem.name }}</h3> <img src="../../assets/home/icons/arrow-right.svg"></div>
</router-link>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'relatedSection',
  props: {
      compItems: {
          type: Array
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Below is an example of a view component defining router.

```
data () {
  return {
    compItems: [
      { name: 'Links', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg', router: 'links'}, 
      { name: 'Form Elements', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg', router: 'form-elements'},
      { name: 'Avatars', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg', router: 'avatars'},
      { name: 'Badges', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg',  router: 'badges'}
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is the console error I'm getting.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:**

Here's a snapshot of the router file:

```
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  props: true,
  component: Home
}, {
  path: '/avatars',
  name: 'avatars',
  props: true,
  component: Avatars
}, {
  path: '/badges',
  name: 'badges',
  props: true,
  component: Badges
}, {
  path: '/buttons',
  name: 'buttons',
  props: true,
  component: Buttons
}, {
  path: '/breadcrumbs',
  name: 'breadcrumbs',
  props: true,
  component: Breadcrumbs
}, {
  path: '/form-elements',
  name: 'form-elements',
  props: true,
  component: FormElements
}, {
  path: '/icons',
  name: 'icons',
  props: true,
  component: Icons
},
 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router's route definitions all have lowercase `name` properties.  When you use a `<router-link>` to access them by name, you need to use an exact match, but your `compItems` have capitalized names.

Also, you are using route params in the link but none of your routes have any defined.

Here is a refactoring to make the code clearer and correct:

```html
<template v-for="compItem in compItems">
  <router-link :to="{ name: compItem.name }" class="cz-ds-view-related-comp">
    <div class="related-comp_icon">
      <img class="related-comp_icon" :src="require('@/assets/home/icons/' + compItem.atomicIcon + '')" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="related-comp_title">
      <h3>{{ compItem.title }}</h3>
      <img src="../../assets/home/icons/arrow-right.svg">
    </div>
  </router-link>
</template>
```

```js
data () {
  return {
    compItems: [
      { title: 'Links', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg', name: 'links'}, 
      { title: 'Form Elements', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg', name: 'form-elements'},
      { title: 'Avatars', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg', name: 'avatars'},
      { title: 'Badges', atomicIcon: 'atom.svg',  name: 'badges'}
    ]
  }
}
```